# Show IP address of currently mounted CIFS share

Tags: linux, mount, ip, cifs, shared-folders

A linux client mounts a Windows share resolved by FQDN configured in `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
//fqdn.windows.share/theShare /local/mount/point cifs [...]
```

Due to infrastructure changes the IP address of the share has changed.

I expected the locally mounted share to resolve the IP address at access time, but it doesn't. The attempt to list the contents of the local resource like

```
ls -lah /local/mount/point
```

fails due to connection problems (sorry, can't reproduce the error message).

Now I wanted to list the *currently used ip address* of the mounted share, but I couldn't figure out how to do. So the question is

*How do I list the currently used IP address of an already mounted CIFS share
(... or details of active mount point containing the IP address)*?

Commands like `mount`, `findmnt` or inspecting `/proc/mounts` didn't help (did I miss an option?).

To be clear: I don't want to query the currently active IP address of the share, which I can query from DNS at any time. Even there is no problem while remounting the share using the new IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
netstat -an --inet | grep "445 "
```

you will get someting like

```
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:23716      8.8.4.4:445          ESTABLISHED
```

where

- 445 is port number for cifs (you need to quote to include a space)
- `netstat --inet -an` will display tcp connection (`-n` is for numeric)

Edit : you may need to use `df` or `mount` before.

Edit2 :

to get IPs

```
netstat -an --inet | awk '$5 ~ /:445$/ { split($5,A,":") ; print A[1] ; }'
```

Comment: Great answer, completely missed to inspect open sockets. Based on your answer: I use _lsof_ instead of _netstat_, because it's missing on some systems. While I couldn't get _lsof_ get to display the connected IP address (maybe you do and add it to your answer?), the command `ss -at '( dport = :445 )'` (whitespaces inside brackets are important!) does.